# Any reliable, cross-browser way to distribute the remaining space in parent element between several DIVs?

Tags: css

## Background

I am working on a browser-based UI that needs to fill the entire screen without any scrolling. The basic layout is like this:

[image: layout sketch]

## What I want to achieve

The title div should has a fixed height (2em) and the rest 4 divs/panels should devide the remaining space of the screen according to percentages I set.

## What I've tried

The best solution I've found is " [CSS - How to force elements to 100% of remaining/available space of parent element without extending beyond it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778306/css-how-to-force-elements-to-100-of-remaining-available-space-of-parent-eleme) ", which involves using a container div with `position:absolute`. This works across all browsers, but requires some additional DIVs to be created. Also, panel 2 can sometimes be forced to start on the next line due to [inaccuracies in percentage widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197708/html-css-can-percentage-width-divs-always-completely-fill-their-parent-containe).

My previous solution was based on CSS3 [Flexbox](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/), but the model is flawed as it does not resize child elements that have a percentage height after stretching the container boxes (at least Chrome doesn't). (The newer flex-* attributes are only implemented in Chrome and the standard is still changing.)

I have also tried the [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/calc) function; however, it's not yet implemented in Chrome. Also, it requires hard-coding the height of the title element in two places, which I've been trying to avoid.

**Edit:**

## What am I looking for

Just to be clear, I am not asking for a perfect/pure-CSS solution (as none seems to exist). If anyone can suggest any jQuery plug-in or open-source framework that can do this, it would be good enough for me.

In addition, I don't require any backwards compatibility with browser releases before 2012. (As long as the solution uses technology that is implemented in some browser and is going to be implemented by Firefox and Chrome in the near future, it's good enough for me.)

Comment: I will be frank. Its a boring work, and no code from you side and no bounties too. Some people like me will be very uninterested to do this for you.

Comment: @Starx It says I can't put a bounty on this until after 2 days, but I do intend to offer one. Also, the point of this question is not to solve my specific problem, but to find a general solution for this kind of UI work. I just want to see if there's any better solutions out there in case I missed them. Even if there's none, this could serve as a reference for people doing similar stuff.

Comment: What's so bad about throwing in some extra markup? It might be just some additional 10 or 20 characters

Comment: @yunzen There're other CSS and jQuery code in my project that assumes some div is a direct children of its container div. If I add these additional divs for layout, I have go back and check all the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A little something thrown together:
http://jsfiddle.net/gDTGn/2/

Comment: I had tried using jQuery's resize() before, but it didn't work for some reason. I'll try this again. Also, javascript is a bit slow compared to my current CSS solution, but since the screen is rarely resized, it's acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure CSS version:

http://jsfiddle.net/t0nyh0/KHzsg/63/

The trick to this technique is using `position:absolute` and using `top`, `bottom`, and `height` to create a fixed header with expanding panels.  It is also really important to use:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

to make the height and width calculations consistent across browsers.  Tested and works in IE9, Firefox, and Chrome.

Comment: Sadly, this is not downwards compatible

Comment: Please read the FIRST(!!) paragraph under "What I've tried". The box-sizing attribute is very useful info though.

Answer (score 2):

Pure CSS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ehqcx/7/embedded/result/

This assumes you set width that don't sum up than more than 100%, the small gap at the right side can usually be fixed by using the same background or the background of the page. An alternative is to introduce some Javascript that sets the width of the last panel correctly, but that should be some trivial jQuery code... `$("#panels .small:last").width(browser width - other small panels);`

Should work correctly for the height, think away the jsFiddle header which takes away some height...

**Edit:**

> Meh, seems the `#title` is bugging me... http://fiddle.jshell.net/ehqcx/7/show/light/
>
> *ECMAScript is the way to go, leaving my answer in place because of the other simplicity...* :(

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="title">Title!</div>
    <div id="panels">
        <div id="panel0" class="small">0</div>
        <div id="panel1" class="small">1</div>
        <div id="panel2" class="small">2</div>
        <div id="panel3" class="wide">3</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```css
* { margin, padding: 0px; }
#content { background-color: black; }
#title { background-color: red; }
#panels { background-color: orange; }
#panel0 { background-color: purple; }
#panel1 { background-color: brown; }
#panel2 { background-color: orange; }
#panel3 { background-color: green; }

html, body, #content, #panels { max-height: 100%; height: 100%; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; }
#panels .small { float: left; }
#panels .wide { clear: both; }

#title { height : 2em; }
#panels .small { height: 75%; }
#panels .wide { height: 25%; }
#panel0, #panel1, #panel2 { width: 33.33%; }
```

Comment: At one point, I was actually using a jQuery fn that subtracts the height of elements with absolute heights (e.g. the title) and redistribute the reset according to the percentages, but that is fragile and slow. The whole purpose of this question is to find a solution that uses as much CSS as possible. Still, thank you for your effort.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141148/css-two-column-div-layout-misaligns-when-zoom-changes ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using the new CSS3 flexbox model. It was basically designed to solve the problem you are facing.

Here is a simple [example](http://dabblet.com/gist/2048574):

CSS:

```
*{margin:0 padding:0;}
html{height:100%;}
body{height:100%; display:box; box-orient:vertical;}
body > div {box-flex:1; border:1px solid black;}
.header {box-flex:0; height:4em;}
.content { 
  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal;
}
.content div {
  box-flex: 1;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div class="header">Title</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div>Panel 0</div>
        <div>Panel 1</div>
        <div>Panel 2</div>
    </div>
    <div>Panel 3</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It has good [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, with planned support in IE.

Comment: @bookcasey Flexbox will not work. Flex will add white space into the elements. So elements with more content will have more space. Just add some more text into Panel 0 and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

### edit 2:

Tested it in

- Chrome/Safari: some 1 or two pixel failure, because of percent calculations
- FireFox: Perfect
- IE9: Perfect
- Opera: Can't have decimal places in percentage width values. This is **bad**
- lte IE8: Does not support Array reduce function. One has to make one up (like from here: [Array.reduce](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_reduce.htm)), Then it works at least in IE8

---

### edit 1:

I added horizontal layout and window resize function

---

I've fiddled around a bit:

This is just a demonstration: To have a full fledged application you have to add the programming for the horizontal layout. But it's start

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/PmHtf/

Here is the code

### HTML

```
<div class="full-stretch">
        <div class="flex-layout flex-layout-vertical">
            <div class="flex-layout-fixed" style="height:50px; text-align: center">
                <div class="padding">Title</div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-layout-consume flex-layout-consume-3" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="flex-layout flex-layout-horizontal">
                    <div class="flex-layout-consume flex-layout-consume-1" style="text-align: center">
                        <div class="padding">Panel 0</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-layout-consume flex-layout-consume-1" style="text-align: center">
                        <div class="padding">Panel 1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-layout-consume flex-layout-consume-1" style="text-align: center">
                        <div class="padding">Panel 2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="flex-layout-consume flex-layout-consume-1" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="padding">Panel 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>​
```

### CSS

```
.full-stretch {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right:2px;
    bottom:2px;
    left: 2px;
}
.padding {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right:2px;
    bottom:2px;
    left: 2px;
    border: 1px solid darkGray;
    background: lightBlue;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.flex-layout {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-layout-consume {
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-layout-vertical > .flex-layout-consume {
    width: 100%;
}


.flex-layout-fixed {
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

}
.flex-layout-vertical > .flex-layout-fixed {
    width: 100%;
}
```

### jQuery

```
(function($) {

  var flex = function() {
      $('.flex-layout').each(function() {
          var fixed = $(this).children('.flex-layout-fixed');


          if ($(this).hasClass('flex-layout-horizontal')) { // horizontal
              var fixed_widths = $(this)
                  .children('.flex-layout-fixed')
                  .get()
                  .reduce(function(total, elem) {
                      return (total + $(elem).outerWidth())
                  },0)
              ;
              var remain_width = ($(this).outerWidth() - fixed_widths)/$(this).outerWidth() * 100; // percent
              var consumers = $(this)
                  .children('.flex-layout-consume')
                  .get()
              ;
              var count_consumers = consumers
                  .reduce(function(total, elem) {
                      var cm = parseInt($(elem).attr('class').match(/flex-layout-consume-(\d+)/)[1]);
                      $(elem).data('consume_multiplicator', cm);
                      return total + cm;
                  },0)
              ;
              var consumers_tic = (remain_width/count_consumers)
              $(consumers).each(function() {
                  $(this).width(Math.round((consumers_tic * $(this).data('consume_multiplicator'))*1000)/1000+'%')
              }) 


          } else if ($(this).hasClass('flex-layout-vertical')) { // vertical
              var fixed_heights = $(this)
                  .children('.flex-layout-fixed')
                  .get()
                  .reduce(function(total, elem) {
                      return (total + $(elem).outerHeight())
                  },0)
              ;
              var remain_height = ($(this).outerHeight() - fixed_heights)/$(this).outerHeight() * 100; // percent
              var consumers = $(this)
                  .children('.flex-layout-consume')
                  .get()
              ;
              var count_consumers = consumers
                  .reduce(function(total, elem) {
                      var cm = parseInt($(elem).attr('class').match(/flex-layout-consume-(\d+)/)[1]);
                      $(elem).data('consume_multiplicator', cm);
                      return total + cm;
                  },0)
              ;
              var consumers_tic = (remain_height/count_consumers)
              $(consumers).each(function() {
                  $(this).height(Math.round((consumers_tic * $(this).data('consume_multiplicator'))*1000)/1000+'%')
              }) 
          }
    })
  };
  $(function() {
    flex()
        $(self).resize(flex)
  })                      
}(jQuery))
​
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something in your question, but see if this is what you are looking for. Pure CSS solution that works in all browsers down to IE7.

http://jsfiddle.net/nyHgM/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion (pure css)... Tested on IE7+, Chrome & FF http://jsfiddle.net/victmo/hKGUe/

**HTML**

```
<div id='header'></div>
<div id='col0'></div>
<div id='col1'></div>
<div id='col2'></div>
<div id='footer'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    position:absolute;
}

#header{
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:3em;
}

#footer{
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:2em;
}

#col0,
#col1,
#col2{
    top:3em; /* header height */
    bottom:2em; /* footer height */
    width:33.33%;
}

#col0{ left:0%;   width:30%; } /* left =  0       */
#col1{ left:30%;  width:40%; } /* left =  0 + 30  */
#col2{ left:70%;  width:30%; } /* left = 30 + 40  */




/* Colors */
#header{ background:#bbb; }
#col0{ background:#ccc; }
#col1{ background:#ddd; }
#col2{ background:#eee; }
#footer{ background:#aaa; }

​
```